# Proper Way To Ensure All Save Methods Work: node.js, MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am quite new to MongoDB and Node.JS, and I have a question about what is the proper way to implement multiple save calls in the same route and ensure that they all work, or none do. What I want, is that if one save fails, they both do. Here is some code. It works as expected with no problems, but I have a feeling that it is bad practice.

My `Post` Schema, as you can see, it is just some text, and then an array of pointers to another object called Comment.

```
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    text: String,
    comments : [{
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : "Comment"
    }]
});
```

My `Comment` Schema. All it is, is just some text.

```
var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({ 
    commentText: String
});
```

Now, here is my route...

```
apiRoutes.post("/testCreateComment", function(request, response, next){
    var commentText = request.body.commentText;
    var testID = request.body.testID
    if (!commentText || !testID) //ensures all data is there.
        return next(new Error("Not all the information required was provided."));
    var newComment = new Comment({
        commentText : commentText
    })

    newComment.save(function(err) { //first save the new TestComment.
        if (err) return next(err);
        Post.findById(testID, function(err, found){ //second find the Post object.
            if (err) return next(err);
            found.comments.push(newComment)
            found.save(function(err){ //third, save the Post object with the comment added to the array.
                if (err) return next(err);
                response.json(newComment.getReturn()); // returns some data to be sent
            })
        })
    })
})
```

In this route, there are three methods that must be successful for the entire operation to work. Now, for instance, save that the first `save` works, but for whatever reason the `findById` is unsuccessful. In this circumstance, I would have a comment floating around in the database that is useless.

My question is, what is the proper way to ensure that all three operations are successful and ensure that the problem described above cannot possibly happen?

Comment: Since you are kind of new to this then you should be looking at [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) as an atomic operator, as this is generally much better than manipulating the array of your object "after" reading it and the of course having to `.save()` again. By the same token, I would put a big question mark over the design that is storing comments in another collection, **yet** you are keeping an array on the object. Chances are that embedding the comments would be simpler and more effective here.

Comment: Remove the saved `comment` if error come up when updating `post`, this sample codes may help you. `newComment.save(function(err) { 
        if (err) return next(err);
        Post.update({_id: testID}, {$push: {comments: newComment._id}},
      function(err, found){ 
    if (err) {
     Comments.remove({_id: newComment._id}, function(err1) {
      if (err1)
       return next(err1);
      else
       return next(err);
     });
    } else {
     response.json(newComment.getReturn()); 
    }
        });
    })` and with `$push` to add comment id to post.

Comment: @zangw thanks, that is very helpful, especially with the code example for the $push

Comment: @BlakesSeven I had not considered the possibility of embedding comments. I will be definitely looking into that. Thanks.